# Pasar un array de datos al dataset de un grafico

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Estoy intentando pasar un array de datos que se llama meses para el dataset de un gráfico en chartjs, el problema está en que si lo paso como "meses" me dibuja el gráfico con sus fluctuaciones, pero a la hora de situarme con el mouse sobre los picos y visualizarlos no me muestra bien los valores (sale 0 en todos), y sí me los muestra bien si paso ese array haciendole un slice(0) o pasando los datos literalmente (ejemplo: [123,445,332]), ¿porque ocurre eso?, decir también que la función inicialiarGrafico la llamo desde una función resultado de una petición ajax, aunque no creo que tenga nada ver eso, gracias de antemano.

```
function inicializarGrafico(meses) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('ganancias').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'line',

        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: '#e3ffbc',
                borderColor: '#7c0',
                data: meses.slice(0)
            }]
        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: true
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos el valor de `meses`?

Comment: Si, esto es lo que me saca por consola el console.log, un array normal con números decimales: Array(12) [ 0, 0, 26.99, 214.85, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, … ]

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es porque tengo que pasarle el array como "meses.slice(0)" en vez de simplemente "meses" para que me funcione, he probado también poner todos los valores del array como enteros y sigue igual

Comment: Pues así visto no tiene mucho sentido. ¿Si haces un `typeof meses` y `typeof meses.slice(0)` y un `meses===meses.slice(0)` coinciden?

Comment: Hola Kiko, lo acabo de probar, y parece que en typeof si coinciden, me dice object en los dos, y si comparo meses con meses.slice(0) parece que no coinciden, aunque mostrando los dos por consola me saca la misma información

Comment: Vale, acabo de de probar una cosa y ha pasado algo raro, la salida por consola de los dos array parece ser la misma (0, 0, 26.99, 214.85, 0...), pero si le doy en la flechita para desplegar el array "meses" todos sus valores se ponen a cero, cosa que no pasa con meses.slice(0) que mantiene sus valores

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código de cómo obtienes `meses` y un pantallazo de la consola?

Comment: Va, ya lo resolví, el problema era que tenía un método que reinicializaba el array a cero en las dos posiciones en un lugar equivocado, debajo de inicializarGráfico que era el que cargaba el elemento canvas con datasets, entonces puse este método arriba, antes de inicializar el grafico y ya funciona perfectamente